# Will upgrading from Node.js 0.6 to 0.8 bring some serious advantages to a web app?

Tags: node.js, upgrade

Our website was built on Node.js 0.6 and we are now considering whether there would be some significant benefits if we upgraded it to 0.8 (we'd like to keep our technologies current but it would cost us some time so we need to consider pros and cons carefully).

I made some research but could find what seems "only" like an API cleanup - other than that, it seems that both 0.6 and 0.8 branches should be relatively bug-free and it seems that people use them both in production today. So, is there anything significant I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

[performance](http://www.nodejs-news.com/nodejs-tech/nodejs-0.8-perf/) increased with version 0.8 and its more stable then 0.6